# PHP: Array to string conversion when retrieving outside function

Tags: php, arrays

Good day!

I have a problem here that I can't solve (last 5hrs).

here's my codes:

```
include 'assets\function\retrieveFunction.php';
$loadGradProgram = array();
$x = count(getCourseInfo());
for($i=0;$i<=$x;$i++){
    $loadGradProgram[$i] = getCourseInfo(); 
}
echo $loadGradProgram[0];
```

getCourseInfo function

Solution 1:

```
function getCourseInfo(){
    $getInfo = array();
    include 'assets\database\connect.php';
    $i = 0;
    $x = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT c.courseID, c.courseCode, c.courseTitle, m.description";
    $sql .=" FROM tblcourse as c INNER JOIN tblcoursemajor as m ON c.courseid=m.courseID ORDER BY c.courseID";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $getInfo[$i] = $row;
            $i++;   
        }

        return $getInfo;
    }
}
```

Result: Array to string conversion

Solution 2:

```
function getCourseInfo(){
    $getInfo = array();
    $loadInfo = array();
    include 'assets\database\connect.php';
    $i = 0;
    $x = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT c.courseID, c.courseCode, c.courseTitle, m.description";
    $sql .=" FROM tblcourse as c INNER JOIN tblcoursemajor as m ON c.courseid=m.courseID ORDER BY c.courseID";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $getInfo[$i] = $row;
            $i++;   
        }
        $conn->close();

        for($x,$x<=$i;$x++;){
            $loadInfo[] = implode(',', $getInfo[$x]);
        }

        return $loadInfo;
    }
}
```

Result: Still the same

and this line causing error: echo $loadGradProgram[0];

I use echo just to see if the query is working.

Comment: `getCourseInfo()` returns an array. You can only `echo` scalar values, not arrays. Use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` for debugging.

Comment: you have a multi-dimentionnal array so you have add a depth to access at the data like $loadGradProgram[0][0]

Comment: @MacBooc hi, how can I convert this code to multi-dimensional array based example in w3school? here's my code: 
    $getInfo[] = $row['courseID'];
    $getInfo[] = $row['courseCode'];
    $getInfo[] = $row['courseTitle'];
    $getInfo[] = $row['description'];

based on w3school:

$cars=array
  (
  array("Volvo",100,96),
  array("BMW",60,59),
  array("Toyota",110,100)
  );

Comment: @Mark if my anwser is ok for you, don't forget to validate him, good luck for the next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a multi-dimmentional array like in w3c documentation, you do it like this :

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $getInfo[$i][] = $row['courseID'];
        $getInfo[$i][] = $row['courseCode'];
        ...
        $i++;   
    }

    return $getInfo;
```

then, if you want to diplay an information in the array you can do a foreach loop or a for loop like :

```
foreach($loadGradProgram as $key => $value) // here the key is useless
{
    echo $value[0];
    echo $value[1];
}
```

or directly like this :

```
echo $loadGradProgram[0][0];
echo $loadGradProgram[0][1];
echo $loadGradProgram[1][0];
```

Comment: thanks for the code! I just came up on that idea a while ago but you post first :) thanks for the reply really appreciate it. Done voting your code and accepting your answer :-)